# jQuery: Use insertAfter method to create p tag inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a div tag with p tag inside it by insertAfter method

So now My code is

```
$('<p></p>', {
  'width': '110',
  'height': '110',
}).insertAfter($(this));
```

The output now like this

```
<p style="width:110px;height:110px;"></p>
```

How to make the output to be like this **without repeating insertAfter method**

```
<div id="wrapP"><p style="width:110px;height:110px;"></p></div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('<p></p>', {
  'width': '110',
  'height': '110',
}).insertAfter($(this)).wrap('<div id="wrapP"></div>');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/PCQrP/3/

Comment: Can I add button tag inside the div, so the output be like that `<div id="wrapP"><button class="hello">hello</button><p style="width:110px;height:110px;"></p></div>`

Comment: Thank you for response, Just 1 tiny problem, I need the button outside the p tag not inside

Answer (score 1):

My approach requires creating the parent element first, and then appending the child:

```
$('<div id="wrapP" />').append($('<p></p>', {
  'width': '110',
  'height': '110',
})).insertAfter('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvz7M/